# LINQ Contains Null

Tags: asp.net, linq

I've a LINQ contains empty/null value that works on my local machine but not on my production box. This would be a where clause.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: It's funny that you're asking because it doesn't. Can you edit the question so it describes the problem better?

Comment: Linq contains some classes and programming techniques.  Lists can contain null values.  But this question is a rather confusing mishmash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the limited info you provided, my first guess is that the objects or entities your Linq statement is working against have some null values that you're not expecting when performing an operation within the WHERE lambda. Your test box has everything populated, but the production environment does not. For instance, referencing MyObject.ChildObject.ChildProperty when MyObject has no child will generate a NullReferenceException. If MyObject isn't required to have a ChildObject in some or all circumstances, you must perform simple null checks to handle this case safely.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what the problem was. Not sure I would have figured that out. Thanks again.